# How to pronounce @[name] on Twitter?

Tags: pronunciation, internet, social-media

@ is usually pronounced as "at", but it seems @ is a verb when it means Twitter somebody, like:

> @Tom for more information.
>   Tweet Tom for more information.
>   Contact Tom for more information.

But not:

> At Tom for more information.

Right?

Comment: I don't believe this is an "appropriate" use of the @ symbol in Twitter's context. @Tom may mean either just the user "Tom" on Twitter or "At Tom", but using it to mean "contact Tom on twitter" doesn't make sense. They're leaving out a verb.

Comment: Further reading: https://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/109-tweets-messages/articles/14023-what-are-replies-and-mentions Using @username is a mention or a reply, even in Twitter lingo it does not constitute "contact this person" it just means "at this person"

Comment: Just a note on the Twitter version: Twitter has introdueced a verb to use for this; "tweet". So your second line there would be "Tweet Tom for more information."

Comment: Just a note on writing @Tom in the first place: The username itself is just `Tom` -- he logs in with `Tom` and not `@Tom`. His profile is at `http://twitter.com/Tom`, not `http://twitter.com/@Tom`. You only need to write `@Tom` when sending a message on Twitter, or mentioning him on Twitter and you want him to know about it. When writing outside Twitter, it can also be used as shorthand to indicate a Twitter username, but it's not essential in this case.

Comment: @aws: Correct, it should be tweet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, @ is always pronounced as *at* because that is what it stands for. Nevertheless, @John can mean different things in different contexts, such as *contact John*. Read it the way you would be best understood.

Comment: For example, YouTube used to tweet “I uploaded **an** @ YouTube video” on your behalf, which I always found strange because in that context I wouldn’t pronounce the “@”—it’s just a code to linkify a username. Now I believe they use “**a** @ YouTube video”.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `@` symbol may originally have been used for this exact purpose, actually.  To my knowledge it was originally used in e-mail, where the writer was supposed to think of a person as being 'at' a particular place; so, when writing the e-mail as To `john@berkeley.edu`, the writer could be thinking they were writing to John at Berkeley educational institute.

With Twitter (and other systems which prefix usernames with `@`), the meaning changes a little, in that the `@` is no longer prefixing the person's location, but the person themselves.  However, when addressing a message to a person, it could conceptually be substituted with the word 'at' and still make sense.

> I'm tweeting the message at John216.

So in the above sentence, 'at' is performing a double task of both being a preposition, and indicating that the `@` character begins the person's username.  Of course in English, you'd generally use 'to' instead of 'at' there, but language evolves.  In addition, the word 'at' may be convenient to indicate that there is a subtle difference between tweeting 'at' someone and saying something 'to' someone; with a tweet, you're kind of doing a "fire and forget"; you don't know whether the person will read the message, but you're addressing it to them.  If you say something 'to' someone, you know they're hearing the message.

Maybe sending online messages 'at' usernames will become a new common expression?

Comment: +1 Great information on the usage of 'at', very helpful for me.

Comment: It’s “original” on the internet, but not in real life—the @ sign used to denote “each at” or “at the rate of” on invoices, e.g., “1 dozen apples @ 60¢”.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, "tweet Tom," or "tweet at Tom."

Comment: "Tweet Tom" would be the right form, as Twitter has introduced as the way to say it.

Answer (score 1):

"@Tom" just means "Twitter account Tom"

If you want to say contact Tom, you should write something like:

Tweet @Tom for more information - the @ is always pronounced 'at'